# compare two files, print header if

Tags: regex, awk, compare

I have two files. 1st line being the header line.

File1

```
start end
234 789
678 780
125 457
534 988
```

File2

```
start end abc efg hij klm nmo
234 789 NA NA 01 02 NA
678 780 01 NA NA NA NA
125 457 NA 01 01 NA 02
534 988 NA NA NA NA 02
```

Now I want to compare these two files; coloumn1 and column2 of File1 with Column1 and Column2 of File2. If they match, I want to print a third file with column1 and column2 of File2 and then the header of the columns for which the field character is not equal to 'NA' like the following output file

```
start end
234 789 hij, klm
678 780 abc
125 457 efg, hij, nmo
534 988 nmo
```

I only know to compare lines; but dont know will it be possible to print the headers which dont match the pattern 'NA'.

Comment: Put yourself in our place and read the question. Do you notice something?

Comment: I think this would be tricky to do using regex. Can we use anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `awk -f a.awk file2 file1`, where `a.awk` is:

```
NR==FNR {
    if (NR==1) {
        split($0,b)
        next
    }
    s="";
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i!="NA") {
            if (s) 
                s=s", " b[i]
            else
                s=b[i]
        }
    }
    a[$1,$2]=s
    next
}
FNR==1 {next}
($1,$2) in a {
    print $1,$2,a[$1,$2]
}
```

Output:

```
234 789 hij, klm
678 780 abc
125 457 efg, hij, nmo
534 988 nmo
```

Comment: This will be slow for big files because you are reading file2 first. It would be best to read file1 first and process file2 when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f ./script.awk File1 File2 > File3
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
NR==1 {

    h=$0
    next
}

FNR==NR {

    a[$1,$2]
    next
}

FNR==1 {

    split($0, b)
    print h

    next
}

($1,$2) in a {

    for (i=3;i<=NF;i++) {

        c = ($i != "NA" ? b[i] : "")

        if (c) {

            r = (r ? r ", " : "") c
        }
    }

    print $1, $2, r
    r = c = ""
}
```

Results and contents of `File3`:

```
start end
234 789 hij, klm
678 780 abc
125 457 efg, hij, nmo
534 988 nmo
```